# Extract error information from Angular 4 error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The following method in an Angular 4 app is throwing an error:

```
getAll() {
    console.log('Inside getAll!');
    return this.http.get('http://ip.addr:4000/some.pdf')
               .map((response: Response) => response.blob())
               .catch((err:Response) => {
                   console.log('Error block!');
                   let details = err.json();

                   return Observable.throw(details);
               });
}
```

The Firefox console prints `"Error Block"`, which indicates that the `http.get()` has thrown an error, which has been trapped in the `catch()` block.  However, the information about the error is not being exposed for use in debugging.

The error in the console is `ERROR TypeError: err is undefined`

**What specific changes need to be made to the code above so that more relevant information about the error can be printed out in the console?**

Comment: May I just ask why not handle the errors in the subscriptions error block?

Comment: @Mihailo I am learning Angular 4 and TypeScript by decomposing sample apps and reading books and reading tutorials, etc.  I don't know what you are suggesting because I need to stumble through problems like this several times before I get the reference points.  Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration time.

I suggest you split this into two parts.
Firstly lets make the http request and the resulting **Observable** in a service.

#### example.service.ts

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get('http://ip.addr:4000/some.pdf', { responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob })
                    .map((res: Response) => res.blob());
};
```

And lets use our **Observable** we made in the `getAll` method in our imaginary component.

#### example.component.ts

```
constructor(
    private exampleService: ExampleService
){};

ngOnInit(){
    this.getThePDF();
};

getThePDF(){
    this.exampleService.getAll().subscribe(
            res => console.log('All is cool, here you go', res),
            err => console.error('All is not so cool :(', err)
        );
};
```

This is obviously not all the data you'll need I just pointed out the important parts *(excluding the imports etc.)*. This is the way I handle http requests, and it should work for you as well.

Comment: The problem is that the PDF is not being served. The catch block is already printing failure console output messages.  Therefore, your answer does not add anything new.  What I need is diagnostic information about why the PDF is NOT being served.  But the stack trace only has references to the JavaScript files and NOT to the actual TypeScript source that I need for debugging.

Comment: Part of what I am asking is how to get TypeScript line numbers in the stack trace.